# Can i execute custom commands in a rich text editor (iframe with design mode on)?

Tags: javascript, text-editor, richtext, designmode

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla).

Is it possible to create custom commands (and how) for the function execCommands?

I need custom commands for custom markup.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that you can override execCommand. Could you perceivably do a conditional check which chooses whether to run execCommand or a custom handler accordingly?

ie:

```
if(markup is custom){
    /* Execute custom command... */
} else {
    /* Execute custom handler... */
}
```

This may just be teaching grandmothers to suck eggs...

As a tip, you may get more accurate answers with more in-depth examples of what you want to achieve.